# Evaluate if a Value Does Not Exists in Another Table

Tags: r

**df1:**

```
a = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12) 
b = c("NA", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "aa") 
c = c("bb", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa")
d = c("aa", "cc", "bb", "aa", "aa", "aa")
e = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
df1 = data.frame(a, b, c, d, e)
```

**df2:**

```
f = c("aa", "bb")
df2 = data.frame(f)
```

I want to evaluate df1 columns b,c,d to see if the value is **not** in df2. If it is, then keep the value. If it's not then input "Rare". Needs to ignore NAs.

**Output:**

```
a  b    c    d    e
2  NA   bb   aa   true
3  bb   aa   rare false
5  rare bb   bb   true
8  aa   rare aa   false
10 bb   aa   aa   true
12 aa   aa   aa   false
```

Comment: Your df's construction leads to "NA"not `NA`. Is `df2` just one vector?

Comment: A `base` solution: `df1[c("b","c","d")]<-sapply(df1[c("b","c","d")], function(x) ifelse(x %in% 
df2$f | is.na(x),x, "rare"))`. You can also `grep`/`match` for the columns you wish to replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your columns are `as.character()`, then (and considering your NA is a string just as you define it)

```
df1[2:4] <- lapply(df1[2:4], function(i)replace(i, !i %in% c('NA', df2$f), 'rare'))

df1
#   a    b    c    d     e
#1  2   NA   bb   aa  TRUE
#2  3   bb   aa rare FALSE
#3  5 rare   bb   bb  TRUE
#4  8   aa rare   aa FALSE
#5 10   bb   aa   aa  TRUE
#6 12   aa   aa   aa FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
a = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12) 
b = c(NA, "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "aa") 
c = c("bb", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa")
d = c("aa", "cc", "bb", "aa", "aa", "aa")
e = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
df1 = data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, stringsAsFactors = F)
#Data2
f = c("aa", "bb")
df2 = data.frame(f,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Code
df1 %>% mutate(across(c(b:d), ~ ifelse(.%in% df2$f | is.na(.), ., 'rare')))
```

Output:

```
   a    b    c    d     e
1  2 <NA>   bb   aa  TRUE
2  3   bb   aa rare FALSE
3  5 rare   bb   bb  TRUE
4  8   aa rare   aa FALSE
5 10   bb   aa   aa  TRUE
6 12   aa   aa   aa FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `dplyr`, but it uses `where` instead.

```
library(dplyr) # version >=1.0.0
df1 %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ifelse((. %in% df2$f )| is.na(.), ., "rare")))
#>    a    b    c    d     e
#> 1  2 <NA>   bb   aa  TRUE
#> 2  3   bb   aa rare FALSE
#> 3  5 rare   bb   bb  TRUE
#> 4  8   aa rare   aa FALSE
#> 5 10   bb   aa   aa  TRUE
#> 6 12   aa   aa   aa FALSE
```